# What are the differences between accounts and users table in SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm

I don't quite understand why those tables is split into different tables? What are the reasons? Is it semantically has different meanings?

Accounts: http://apidocs.sugarcrm.com/schema/6.5.18/corp/tables/accounts.html

Users:
http://apidocs.sugarcrm.com/schema/6.5.18/corp/tables/users.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users are those that log into your SugarCRM instance. Accounts are for keeping track of your customers, vendors, etc. They don't log into your SugarCRM.